# In how many ways can the letters be arranged so $A$ is not adjacent to $B$, $B$ is not adjacent to $G$, and $G$ is not adjacent to $D$?

Tags: combinatorics

The letters are $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J$. The question is in how many ways can you order the letters in line, such that:
$A$ is not adjacent to $B$,
$B$ is not adjacent to $G$,
$G$ is not adjacent to $D$?
I used the inclusion–exclusion principle and got to the following answer:
$10! - 2 \cdot3 \cdot 9! + 4\cdot8! + 8\cdot7!-2\cdot7!$
But the final answer in my book doesn't include the $+ 8\cdot7!$

This number represents the number of ways to order the letters such that $A$ is adjacent to $B$ and also $G$ is adjacent to $D$...
Am I wrong anywhere?

Comment: What does "near" mean here?

Comment: It means that is not consecutive, before or after @HenningMakholm

Comment: What the heck does 'near' mean?  I assume you mean "adjacent to" but, sheesh, make an *effort* to be precise rather than subjective.

Comment: you're right... fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

Let S be the set of all orderings, and let $E_1$ be the orderings with A and B adjacent, $E_2$ be the orderings with B and G adjacent, and $E_3$ be the orderings with G and D adjacent.

Then $|\overline{E_1}\cap\overline{E_2}\cap \overline{E_3}|=|S|-|E_1|-|E_2|-|E_3|+|E_1\cap E_2|+|E_2\cap E_3|+|E_1\cap E_3|-|E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3|$

$\hspace{1.4 in}=10!-3\cdot2\cdot9!+2\cdot8!+2\cdot8!+2^2\cdot8!-2\cdot7!$

$\hspace{1.4 in}=10!-3\cdot2\cdot9!+8\cdot8!-2\cdot7!$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $- 2|E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3|$ as $E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3 \subset E_1\cap E_2; E_2 \cap E_3; E_1 \cap E_3$ and was therefore *triple* counted?

Comment: @fleablood $E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3 \subset E_1$, $E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3 \subset E_2$, and $E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3 \subset E_3$.

Comment: Right so the union was subtracted 3 times then it was added back 3 times and ... hmm.

Comment: Indeed this is correct.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why I did that...

Answer (score 0):

"This number represents the number of ways to order the letters such that AA is adjacent to BB and also GG is adjacent to DD..."

Except that should be 8*8!.  You are rearranging (AB)(GD)CEFHIJ.  8 elements.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can also be checked with the following Ruby code

```
answer=0
['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'].permutation(10).map(&:join).each {|p|
    answer+=1 unless ['AB','BA','BG','GB','GD','DG'].any? {
        |letters| p.include?(letters)
    }
}
puts answer
```